# Why is the ul with class "subnav" not bigger?

Tags: html, css

The ul with class "subnav" should be bigger. I noticed it because the background color is only shown in a small area. If i hover nav ul li the "subnav" ul is not going out of the nav. Strangely the li a inside "subnav" are shown correct and are going outside the nav just fine.
Only when I give the "subnav" a specific height it will go outside the nav.

```css
header {
  background-image: url("../images/header.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 0 -15vh;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 40vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10vh;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
}

nav ul {
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 3fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  align-items: center;
}

nav ul li {
  position: relative;
}

nav ul li a {
  color: #1b1a5c;
}

nav ul li .far {
  margin-right: 0.5em;
  color: #1b1a5c;
}

nav ul li .fas {
  margin-right: 0.5em;
  color: #1b1a5c;
}

#logo {
  height: 100%;
}

#logo img {
  max-height: 100%;
}

.subnav {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #b18e4a;
  width: 80%;
  transform: translateX(10%);
  padding: 0.8em;
  z-index: 1;
}

.subnav li {
  margin: 0.4em;
}

.subnav li a {
  color: white;
}

.subnav li a:hover {
  color: #1b1a5c;
}

nav ul li:hover .subnav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li id="logo">
        <a href="index.html"><img src="images/salonorchesterlogo.png" alt="Logo des Salonorchester Zürich Oberland"></a>
      </li>
      <li><a href=""><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i>Konzerte</a>
        <ul class="subnav">
          <li><a href="konzerte_kalender.html">Kalender</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Billette</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href=""><i class="far fa-newspaper"></i>News</a></li>
      <li><a href=""><i class="fas fa-info"></i>Über uns</a>
        <ul class="subnav">
          <li><a href="ueber_uns_orchester.html">Orchester</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Vorstand</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Dirigent</a></li>
          <li><a href="ueber_uns_kontakt.html">Kontakt</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "It should be bigger".

Comment: The background only covers the top part of my links inside "subnav". Altough the links are displayed as a column. When I inspect "subnav" its very small and the links are overflowing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `height: 100%` property you are setting in the `nav ul` selector is targeting the top-level `ul` inside `nav` as well as your `ul.subnav`.  You could either change the `nav ul` to `nav > ul` if you intend it to be specific only to the top-level `ul` or you could override that height in your `.subnav` block:

```css
.subnav {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #b18e4a;
  width: 80%;
  transform: translateX(10%);
  padding: 0.8em;
  z-index: 1;
  height: auto; /* ADD THIS TO OVERRIDE HEIGHT: 100% SET IN `nav ul` block */
}
```

You can see this in action in the snippet below:

```css
header {
  background-image: url("../images/header.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 0 -15vh;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 40vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10vh;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
}

nav ul {
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 3fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  align-items: center;
}

nav ul li {
  position: relative;
}

nav ul li a {
  color: #1b1a5c;
}

nav ul li .far {
  margin-right: 0.5em;
  color: #1b1a5c;
}

nav ul li .fas {
  margin-right: 0.5em;
  color: #1b1a5c;
}

#logo {
  height: 100%;
}

#logo img {
  max-height: 100%;
}

.subnav {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #b18e4a;
  width: 80%;
  transform: translateX(10%);
  padding: 0.8em;
  z-index: 1;
  height: auto; /* ADD THIS TO OVERRIDE HEIGHT: 100% SET IN `nav ul` block */
}

.subnav li {
  margin: 0.4em;
}

.subnav li a {
  color: white;
}

.subnav li a:hover {
  color: #1b1a5c;
}

nav ul li:hover .subnav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li id="logo">
        <a href="index.html"><img src="images/salonorchesterlogo.png" alt="Logo des Salonorchester Zürich Oberland"></a>
      </li>
      <li><a href=""><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i>Konzerte</a>
        <ul class="subnav">
          <li><a href="konzerte_kalender.html">Kalender</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Billette</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href=""><i class="far fa-newspaper"></i>News</a></li>
      <li><a href=""><i class="fas fa-info"></i>Über uns</a>
        <ul class="subnav">
          <li><a href="ueber_uns_orchester.html">Orchester</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Vorstand</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Dirigent</a></li>
          <li><a href="ueber_uns_kontakt.html">Kontakt</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

For what it is worth, I would also revisit your decision to set the positioning to `absolute` and then use `translateX` to position the element, as opposed to just using some combination of `top`, `left`, `right`, and `bottom`.  I don't know that there is anything *explicitly* wrong with that, but I wonder if you might get some unexpected behavior by mixing your intentions there.

Comment: Ok I removed ```absolute```. Now "subnav" is shown correctly but it does shift up ```nav ul li```

Comment: Nice! Now I also understand why this happened. I will make sure to be more specific with my selectors in future :)

Comment: @Defgun -- glad this helped-- regarding `absolute`/`translateX`, I actually was trying to convey you should remove the `translateX`, and instead add `top: <some value in px or %` and `left: 10%` to the block in order to position it appropriately.  Sorry if I was unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Here try this. I gave your .subnav class the style `height: auto;`. Also I removed your padding and width styles.

```
.subnav {
    height: auto;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #b18e4a;
    /*transform: translateX(10%);*/
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks a lot Adam!

Answer (score 0):

add the height to nav ul li:hover .subnav

```
nav ul li:hover .subnav {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 align-items: flex-start;
 justify-content: flex-start;
 height: 150px
}
```

Comment: This would work yes. But I have not the same amount of links inside those subnavs. So I don't want to give a fixed height.